Will a Z diode protect component if no current if flowing?
Probably a noob question, but I'm new to electronics and can't manage to find a clear answer. I have a DC/DC converter that takes up to 100V input and outputs 12V.
This converter takes a second signal, 12V, to turn it on. Now I don't want to use 2 power sources, I was planning on using a Zener diode to clamp my 100V power supply (battery) to 12V.
That being said, as the 12V is only a contact, no current is drawn. Therefore, voltage won't really be clamped as the diode needs current above its knee current.
I know I could bridge it with a resistor going back to GND and create a very low current to make it work.
That being said, two points are not clear for me:

I'm inferring that the 12V contact is just a contact and absolutely no current is drawn. I checked it with my variable power supply bench, but it could be an extremely low current under what the bench is able to display. I don't know how it's made inside, I assume the contact activates some sort of transistor (MOSFET or BJT I guess). If it's a MOSFET, there really won't be any current drawn apart from the initial capacitance draw.
If no current is drawn, does the voltage alone can damage the component? I've seen many projects where a MOSFET gate is protected with a Z diode.


As @Tyassin mentioned, provide a datasheet for the converter.  There's a chance that you're making this task harder than it needs to be.

Often the enable signal is also "active low", which would permit you to just short it to ground when you want to turn the power supply on - either permanently or through a switch, relay, etc...

Unfortunately, it's a converter in an existing circuit for which no datasheet nor reference number is provided. So I'm completely in the dark on this side :/


That being said, as the 12V is only a contact, no current is drawn.

If you are using a 12 V zener in parallel with the input pin, then the zener itself will draw current, so there is no problem:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The current will be roughly \$ (100 V - 12 V)/R_1\$ (only roughly because the zener voltage depends on temperature, manufacturing variation, etc.)
If you tried to use an 88 V zener in series with the control pin, you'd have a problem:

simulate this circuit
Here there is almost no current through the zener, and as you suspected it therefore doesn't enter zener operation, and it doesn't produce the required 88 V drop, so your converter might be damaged.
You could alleviate that problem by providing a shunt resistor from the control pin to ground --- but I still don't advise that because if the 100 V input has some variations (perhaps sometimes it is 90 V and sometimes it is 110 V) those variations will be transferred directly through to the converter input pin (in the example, leading to input voltages from 2 V to 22 V, which on the low side probably won't produce valid operation and on the high side might damage the controller).

Thanks for your detailed answer and explanation! You guessed it well, input voltage isn"t constant as it's a battery, so it depends on the state of charge (from slightly more than 100V all the way down to 55V).

Is there a datasheet for this converter?
But usually the Enable pin (if this is the case) is high impedance so no significant current is drawn.
You could just use two very high resistances, 750K and 100K in series and then use the voltage over the 100K. This give some 11.7V.
Just make sure to select some resistors that can handle the power/voltage.

What does "tab out over the 100K some 11.7V" mean?
